# Display items based on user

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am running Virtuemart 1.1.9 on top of Joomla 1.5.25.

How can I display items based on the user that is logged in??

For example, I've set up 2 Shopper groups, for each shopper group, I've set up 2 of the same individual products with different prices for each shopper group.   For example, let me expand:-  'Shopper Group A' belongs to product list of 'Product A' and 'Shopper Group B' belongs to product list of 'Product B'.  The public (non-logged and with no special shopper group privileges) can only see 'Shopper Group A' with products belonging to 'Product A' and no other shopper group can see other shopper group products.  Now when someone who belongs to 'Shopper Group B' logs in, they will only be seeing products belonging to 'Product B' and nothing else.  This all works very well and as predicted.

AHIA,
LarryR....

Comment: In what way do you mean "based on the user"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pruchasing Rules [By Polished Geek, LLC](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-administration/11695)...exactly what I was looking for & works exactly as they describe!!!!

Comment: When i use your link it is not working. it returns "404 not found"

Answer (score 1):

That's going to take a lot of custom code no matter how you do it. Here's a rough idea of what you need to do -

1. Determine how you are going to group users. You can probably use VM groups or Joomla user groups
2. Modify every VM page that displays products, the queries will have to be changed in order to select the right products
3. Determine how you are going to associate a product with a user group. This can probably be done with product types.

Before you jump in to this though you should seriously consider upgrading to Joomla 2.5 and VM 2.0 since VM 1.x is already obsolete and Joomla 1.5.x will be soon.

Comment: this is what I am looking for...http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=35677.0